# Why does finding a player after using /execute positioned trigger even if there is no player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The command block should say 'Minecraft' only if a player stands at 'xyz: 0 20 0'. But it does so no matter where I stand. Could somebody tell me what I did wrong and fix this command please?

```
/execute if entity @p positioned 0 20 0 run say Minecraft
```

I'm playing on a single player creative world on Minecraft Java Edition 1.16.3.

Answer (score 15):

### What's the error?

You thought the command would say, "**If there is a player positioned at 0 20 0, say Minecraft.**"

However, it actually says, "**Locate the nearest player; if one is found, make the command execute positioned at 0 20 0: say Minecraft**"

### How to fix it?

```
/execute positioned 0 20 0 if entity @p[distance=..1] run say Minecraft
```

This command says "**Execute this command positioned at 0 20 0: locate the nearest player within 1 block radius of the command's execution position; if one is found, say Minecraft**".

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way to do this using selectors:

```
/execute as @p[x=0.5,y=20.5,z=0.5,distance=..1] run say Minecraft
```

(The `x=`, `y=`, and `z=` aren't strictly necessary.)

Conversely, you could also specify the volume of the search space like so:

```
/execute as @p[x=0,y=20,z=0,dx=1,dy=1,dz=1] run say Minecraft
```